# Confusion on Thread setDeaemon in java

Tags: java, multithreading

According to java when setDaemon is set to true

> it does not prevent the JVM from
>   exiting when the program finishes but
>   the thread is still running. An
>   example for a daemon thread is the
>   garbage collection.

From the following code sample , the thread created by main thread stops executing when `setDaemon` is set to **true**, actually it should keep on running . when `setDaemon`  is set **false** the child thread print value of i even though main thread exited.
kindly clarify my doubt.

```
public class DeamonSample implements Runnable
{
      public void run()
      {
            try 
{
System.out.println("T1 started...");

                  for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
                  {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        System.out.print(i+" ");
                  }
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                  System.out.println("T1 ended...");
            }

      }


      /**
      * @param args
      */
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Main Started...");
            System.out.println("Main Thread Type="+Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
            DeamonSample deamonSample=new DeamonSample();
            Thread t1=new Thread(deamonSample);
            t1.setDaemon(true);
            t1.start();
            System.out.println("T1 Type="+t1.isDaemon());
            System.out.println("Main Thread Type="+Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
            System.out.println("Main ended...");
      }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default threads are not daemon threads. If you get to the end of your main with any thread that's not a daemon then the process will keep running. By calling `setDaemon(true)` you're telling the JVM that your thread shouldn't block shutdown at the end of main.

Answer (score 1):

The DeamonSample instance is assuredly not stopped when `t1.setDaemon(true);` is executed; the nondeterminism that you see comes from the prints. Characters are written to thread-local buffers before they are merged into a single stream.

Here's a bit of code to illustrate. Two threads take turns incrementing a counter and printing its state, but the numbers you see may be very much out of order.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class FunnyPrinter extends Thread {
    static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    int parity;

    public FunnyPrinter(int parity) {
        super();
        this.parity = parity;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (;;)
            if (counter.intValue() % 2 == parity)
                System.out.println(counter.incrementAndGet());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FunnyPrinter t1 = new FunnyPrinter(0), t2 = new FunnyPrinter(1);
        t1.start(); t2.start();
    }
}
```

If you need determinism, synchronize on `System.out` and `flush` it before the end of the block.

Answer (score 0):

The main-thread terminates, before your daemon-thread can print out all your numbers...
if your new thread isDaemon = true, try this line after starting the thread ():

```
...
Thread t1=new Thread(deamonSample);
try{
   t1.join();
}catch(InterruptedException ie){
    ie.printStackTrace();
}
...
```

you will see, the daemon-thread will come to an end... (at least, that wouldn´t be multithreading anymore, but that example is for clarifying purpose only)

Answer (score 0):

> *From the following code sample , the thread created by main thread stops executing when setDaemon is set to true*

This will not happen. Check your output again. Your output will contain the following lines:

Main Started...
Main Thread Type=false
T1 Type=true
Main Thread Type=false
Main ended...

> ..actually it should keep on running .

Being a daemon thread, it wont. Since all non-daemon threads (main) have finished, the jvm will exit.

> when setDaemon is set false the child thread print value of i even though main thread exited. kindly clarify my doubt.

Correct